# No module found when packaging addon as zip

Tags: python, import

I have the follow project structure:

```
my_addon: 
   __init__.py
   faa:
      foo.py
```

but when I try to import foo.py from the init file (import faa.foo) I get a "module not found" exception. It does work in VS Code, but it doesn't work when installed in blender
Can someone help me?

Comment: Most likely the best answer will depend on your OS. For windows in a multifile addon setup i use `addon_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` and `for mod in os.listdir(os.path.join(addon_path, folder))` looping through a list of folders to create a list of module names.

Comment: Add a file called `__init__.py` into the `faa` subfolder. The file can be empty, it just has to be there